# Shell script to display environment variables

Tags: bash, shell

This shell script writes my environment variables. If there is an argument, the shell script will `grep` for the argument in the environment variables.

```
PAGER=more
if type less > /dev/null;then PAGER=less; fi
echo $PAGER
if [ -z ${1+x} ]; then printenv|"$PAGER"; else printenv|grep "$1"|"$PAGER"; fi
```

If the above script is correct then I will work on my shell to be able to parse it. It can parse everything except the last line, which I added today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Readability

Just because Bash let's you cram a lot of statements on a single line doesn't mean you should.
I recommend to split this up to multiple lines,
and also to put spaces around `|`, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PAGER=more
if less >/dev/null; then
    PAGER=less
fi
echo $PAGER

if [ -z ${1+x} ]; then
    printenv | "$PAGER"
else
    printenv | grep "$1" | "$PAGER"
fi
```

But if you like compact writing style,
a reasonable compromise is to replace the first `if` statement with an alternative writing style using `&&` like this:

```
less >/dev/null && PAGER=less
```

#### Error handling

I'm not sure if it's intentional,
but if the `less` command doesn't exist (but in most systems it does),
this line will emit an error message:

> ```
> if type less >/dev/null
> ```

To avoid errors, you want to suppress `stderr` too in addition to `stdout`:

```
if type less >/dev/null 2>&1
```

#### Prefer simple solutions

This is hacky, cryptic:

> ```
> if [ -z ${1+x} ]; then
> ```

I suggest a much more readable, simple equivalent:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
```

#### Don't repeat yourself

The `printenv` command is repeated in both branches of the last `if` statement.
You could move it in front of the `if`, like this:

```
printenv | \
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    "$PAGER"
else
    grep "$1" | "$PAGER"
fi
```

However, in this writing style it's important that the `\` on the line before the `if` is the last character on the line directly in front of the line break.